# How to reuse app icon image using `require`?

Tags: react-native, appicon

The react native app icons are put in `ios\VietVanHocTro\Images.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset` and `android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-...` folders.

How can I use these icons in the application without duplicating them?

Can I use `isOS ? require('.../android-icon') : require('../ios-icon')`?

I've tried `require('../ios/app/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon-20.png')` but it gives me undefined as the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use assets from native image location by using the [hybrid app resource method](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#images-from-hybrid-app-s-resources) - `<Image source={{uri: 'icon-20.png''}} style={{width: 40, height: 40}} />`